# How to compare two values in TreeMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I have a TreeMap and I want to compare its `i` and `i+1` value in it. How can I do that. I know that TreeMap is sorted based on its keys but I want to compare the values and can't use sorting as I will loose original form. I want something like this but in TreeMap-

```
int a[] = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
{
     if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
    {
         c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Something like this but in a TreeMap" is a little bit vague to give an answer. You could at least have given the declaration of the Treemap and tell us what types as Key/Value the map holds. But in the end you compare the values like any object in java: By using the compareTo method.

Comment: A `TreeMap` is a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) so you can use the methods of that interface to compare adjacent entries. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can do it like that:

```
        TreeMap<Integer,Integer> tree=new TreeMap<>();          
        tree.put(1,5);
        tree.put(2,6);
        tree.put(3,4);
        tree.put(4,4);   

        Entry<Integer,Integer> entry=tree.firstEntry();
        int c=0;
        while(tree.higherEntry(entry.getKey())!=null) {
            if(entry.getValue()>tree.higherEntry(entry.getKey()).getValue())
                c++;
            entry=tree.higherEntry(entry.getKey());
        }
```

Using the higherEntry, higherKey etc.

By the way in your example you will get an ArrayIndexOutOFBound I think because of  a[i + 1]